# Is Hanumana worshipped anywhere in his infant or child form?

Tags: temple, worship, hanuman

Sri Rama and Sri Krishna are both worshipped in their infant or childhood form. viz. Sri Ramalala (श्री राम-लला), and Sri Laddu Gopala (श्री लड्डू-गोपाल).

Are there any temples where god Hanumana is worshipped in an infant or childlike form?

If yes, any scriptural reference for the same available?

Comment: There are many Balaanjaneya Swami temples in Telugu states and Karnataka. One such temple is in [Kukatpalli](https://youtu.be/oPL5tg7_4IE) which is now part of Hyd. Murti in temple is believed to be 400 years old found in agricultural fields and people from these agricultural castes constructed temple for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Hanumāna is worshipped across India in several forms, even in infant form also.

#### 1. Bālājī Hanumāna Mandira, Mehandīpura (Rājasthāna)

- As per their [official site](http://www.mehandipurbalajidham.com/index.php), in this temple bālājī Hanumāna is consecrated and worshipped in his child (bâla - बाल स्वरुप) form, and thus known as Bālājī Hanumāna.

The temple is considered as famous exorcism center too, for people afflicted with evil beings

---

#### 2. Hanumānagaḍhī (Ayodhya, UP)

- One of the most famous temple is found in the the city of God Râma - Ayodhya itself, in the present day state of Uttar Pradesh, known as **Hanumānagaḍhī (हनुमानगढ़ी)**.

Quoting from the official [tourist guide](https://ayodhya.nic.in/hi/tourist-place/%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8-%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%9D%E0%A5%80/) of the Uttar Pradesh government -

> हनुमान गढ़ी
>
> Hanumāna-gaḍhī Temple
>
> पवनपुत्र हनुमान को समर्पित यहाँ मंदिर अयोध्या रेलवे स्टेशन से १ किमी
> दूरी पर स्थित है, इस मंदिर का निर्माण विक्रमादिय द्वारा करवाया गया था
> जो आज हनुमान गढ़ी के नाम से प्रसिद्ध है| ऐसी मान्यता है की पवनपुत्र
> हनुमान यहाँ रहते हुए कोतवाल के रूप में अयोध्या की रक्षा करते हैं|
> मंदिर के प्रांगन में माता अंजनी के गोद में बैठे बाल हनुमान को दर्शाया
> गया है|

#### Summarized English Translation of the above:

- This temple is said to have been constructed by King Vikramaditya.
- The religious belief associated with this temple is that god Hanumāna, residing in the temple protects the city of Ayodhya as the kotavāla (police).
- In the temple's premises Hanumāna is depicted in his infant form, sitting on his mother Añjanā's lap.

<sup>However, the main idol in the Sanctum Santorum is of the Adult form of Hanumāna.</sup>

(*currently I cannot locate any scriptural references for this though*).

---